# Displaying different views for the same controller, based on the route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an admin interface for a website. I have certain controllers that have admin functions/views that also have user facing views. For example, when a user goes to /blog, it should show the title, date, first paragraph, etc. of each blog post with links to read the whole post. If an admin goes to admin/posts they would see a list of just the blog post titles, how many comments, edit/delete links, link to create a post, etc.

How would I accomplish this? My (simplified) routes files is this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

Do I need to have separate controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when using `namespaces` you want your code to be namespaced as well. I would go for 2 different controllers serving 2 different views.

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
app/controllers/backend/posts_controller.rb
```

or

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
app/controllers/admin_area/posts_controller.rb
```

You get the idea. I would do the same thing with the views.

You controllers would look like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
end

class Backend::PostsController < BackendController
end

class BackendController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: OK I think I see. So I do need to create separate controllers/views for each section. Is there a reason not to keep the client facing parts in the root "namespace" instead of it's own namespace? It seems to me since the routes are /posts and /admin/posts that the admin posts should be in a namespace but front facing posts should not be.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you could approach this, I can't really think of one being "right" over the other.  For simplicity's sake, I'll offer one quick solution, though, admittedly, it's a shortcut.

Presumably, you have a logged in user going to this /admin route, and the current_user would be authorized as an admin, so you can use that to your advantage in your show method.

```
if current_user.admin?
  render 'admin_show'
else
  render 'show'
```

Your views, of course, would render the different implementations.

If you are going to have a number of differences in what the methods do, though, it may be worth creating a new admin_posts_controller.  But if there are only a couple differences, then that could be good enough.

Meh, hope that helps.